# Why is there no right border when printing a ggplot with a ggtheme into word?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, ggthemes

I am creating plots in R markdown to be printed to MS word. When I create a plot using the base R plot() function, there are no borders around the printed plot. Same if I use a basic ggplot. However, if I add a theme using ggthemes, it adds borders to the top, left, and bottom of the printed plot (but not the right).

I don't know why it adds these borders, or why it omits the one on the right-hand side. It appears to occur regardless of which theme I use (I prefer theme_gdocs or theme_clean due to the white backgrounds). Instead of removing all of those borders, I would prefer to actually include borders on all four sides.

Here is my code:
(hopefully the images work)

```
---
title: "ggplot reprex"
author: "Me"
date: "11/5/2019"
output: word_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse); library(ggthemes)

data=pressure
```

Base plot:

```
plot(data)
```

[base plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H1rN.png)

ggplot:

```
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=temperature,y=pressure))+
  geom_point()
```

[ggplot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mavpx.png)

ggplot with ggtheme:

```
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=temperature,y=pressure))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_gdocs()
```

[ggplot with ggtheme image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZx2h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue using the plot.background modification in theme() as follows:

```
ggplot(data=data,aes(x=temperature,y=pressure))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_gdocs()+
  theme(plot.background=element_rect(colour="black",fill=NA,size=1))
```

Thanks to anyone who was working on a fix!